# Removing string quotations without slicing?

Tags: python

I want to analyze inputted strings but the quotation marks are interfering with my analysis. How do I remove quotation marks without using slicing/indexes? Is there something like string.strip() for quotations or a simple expression that is equivalent? Thanks mates!

Comment: [`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) takes arguments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do one of the following:

```
string.strip("'") # strips single quotes away
string.strip('"') # strips double quotes
string.strip("'\"") # both single and double quotes. The double quote in the middle is 'escaped' by the backslash character
```

or

```
string = string.replace("'", "") # replaces single quotes in the string with nothing
string = string.replace('"', '') # for double quotes
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) :

```
string = "'hello'"

print(string.replace("'",""))
# hello
```

Answer (score 1):

`strip` perfectly work for your purpose. Just ask it to remove the quote:

```
>>> string = "'hello'"
>>> print(string.strip("'"))
hello
```